# Convert one format of date to another format using perl Date::Manip

Tags: perl, date, datetime, perl-module

I am trying to convert incoming date into another format below is the code I have written.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
#
use POSIX qw(strftime);
use Date::Manip;
my $string = "Run started at 12:01:48 PM on Aug 19 2016 ";

my @array = split(' ',$string);

$string  = "12:01:48 PM Aug 19, 2016";

$unix_time = UnixDate( ParseDate($string), "%s" );
#print $unix_time;

my $datestring = strftime "%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Y", gmtime($unix_time);
printf("date and time - $datestring\n");
```

I want the output in `Fri Aug 19 12:01:48 2016` but right on PM is not getting considered can you please help me here ?

Comment: So you overwrite `$string` with a clean-up version? Why show us the first `$string` and the `split` to `@array` that you never use at all? That's just confusing. Please [edit] and remove the unused parts. Please also include the output you are getting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered using [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) instead of Date::Manip? It is part of the standard Perl distribution (since Perl 5.10) and is generally considered to be far superior to Date::Manip.

You need to use `strptime()` (string parse time) to convert your string to a Time::Piece object and then `strftime()` (string format time) to convert your object to a string in the required format.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
# We use modern Perl - specifically say()
use 5.010;

use Time::Piece;

my $string = '12:01:48 PM Aug 19, 2016';

my $tp = Time::Piece->strptime($string, '%H:%M:%S %p %b %d, %Y');

say $tp->strftime('%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Y');
```

**Update:** And to answer your original question, I think you're getting burnt by time zones. It seems that `ParseDate()` assumes that the string is in the local time zone - but you're using `gmtime()` to generate your new date string. If you switch that to `localtime()` you will get the answer you want.